# программа почему то не всегда выводит результат полностью , не пойму в чем ошибка

Tags: c++, матрицы

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема , программа некорректно работает при размерности матрицы больше 3 , а именно в X2 выводит две или одну строчку вместо четырех и дальше почему то завершает работу с кодом -121314.. и тд
А иногда и в месте где умножается матрица на обратную(A*(A^(-1)))
Проблема предполагаемо в 205 строчке : вызывается функция summtx(на 51 строчке расположена ф-ция) потом идет  ShowMtx1(X2, size, 1); next
Еще на 206 и 222 в функциях multimass

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
#define clean system("cls");
#define next cout<<endl;
void ShowMtx1(double** A, int size, int size1)//вывод с выравниванием
{
    if (size1 != size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size1; j++)
            {
                cout << fixed << setprecision(4) << setw(8) << A[i][j] << " ";
            }
            next
        }
        next
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                cout << fixed << setprecision(4) << setw(8) << A[i][j] << " ";
            }
            next
        }
        next

    }

}

void MultiMass(double** T, double** B, double** X, int size, int size2)//умножение
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
        {
            X[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
            {
                X[i][j] += T[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
void Summmtx(double** A, double** B, double** C, int size)//вычисление суммы матриц
{

    cout << "B="; next ShowMtx1(B, size, 1); next
        cout << "B="; ShowMtx1(B, size, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {// результат суммирования матриц в новую матрицу
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            C[i][j] = A[i][j] - B[i][j];
        }
        next
    }
    cout << "X2=" << endl;

}
void deleteMtx(double** A, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++)
    {
        delete[] A[i];
    }
    delete[] A;
}
void deleteMtx1(double** B, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        delete[] B[i];
    }
    delete[] B;
}
int Gaussdet(double** A, double** T, double** C, int size)
{
    double** F = new double* [size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)//копия матрицы A
    {
        F[i] = new double[size];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            F[i][j] = A[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "A=" << endl;
    ShowMtx1(F, size, size);//вывод матрицы A
    double** B = new double* [size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { B[i] = new double[1]; }
    cout << "B=" << endl;//вывод матрицы B
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) { B[j][0] = rand()%20; cout << B[j][0] << "\n"; }
    cout << "T=" << endl;//вывод матрицы T
    ShowMtx1(T, size, size); next

        double eps;
    cout << "Enter the epsilon" << endl;
    cin >> eps;// минимальный модуль элемента матрицы //
    while ((eps >= 1) || (eps <= 0)) { cout << "Error , enter the epsilon(<1,>0)" << endl; cin >> eps; }
    //clean
    bool isNull = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        if (A[i][i] == 0)
        {
            isNull = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isNull)
    {
        cout << "Problem on diagonal" << endl;//если находим нуль на главной диагонали, то выводим сообщение  об ошибке
        return 0;
    }
    //проверка на нулевую строку
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            int schet = 0, schet1 = 0;
            if (A[i][j] < eps) schet += 1;

            if ((schet == size - 1) || (schet1 == size - 1))
            {
                cout << "Nulevaya stroka,det=0" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    double temp;
    double det = 1;
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        temp = A[k][k];
        det *= temp;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            A[k][j] /= temp;
            T[k][j] /= temp;
        }

        for (int i = k + 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            temp = A[i][k];

            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                A[i][j] -= A[k][j] * temp;
                T[i][j] -= T[k][j] * temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int k = size - 1; k > 0; k--)
    {
        for (int i = k - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            temp = A[i][k];

            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                A[i][j] -= A[k][j] * temp;
                T[i][j] -= T[k][j] * temp;
            }
        }
    }
    ShowMtx1(A, size, size); next ShowMtx1(T, size, size);
    cout << "det(A)= " << det; next
        cout << "A,right and reverse code" << endl; ShowMtx1(F, size, size); next
        ShowMtx1(T, size, size);
    cout << "T,right and reverse code;T=A^(-1)" << endl; ShowMtx1(T, size, size);
    next
        double** X = new double* [size];// X-матрица решений
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        X[i] = new double[1];
    double** X2 = new double* [size];// X2-копия B
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { X2[i] = new double[1]; }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
            X2[i][j] = B[i][j];
        }
    }
    //ShowMtx1(F, size, size);
    cout << "X=A^(-1)*B" << endl;
    cout << "A^(-1)=" << endl; ShowMtx1(T, size, size);
    cout << "B=" << endl; ShowMtx1(B, size, 1); next
        MultiMass(T, B, X, size, 1); next
        cout << "X=" << endl; ShowMtx1(X, size, 1); next
        cout << "A*X" << endl;
    cout << "A=" << endl; ShowMtx1(F, size, size); next
        cout << "X=" << endl; ShowMtx1(X, size, 1); next
        cout << "B=" << endl; ShowMtx1(X2, size, 1); next//
        MultiMass(T, X, B, size, 1);
    cout << "A*X-B" << endl;

    Summmtx(B, B, X2, size); ShowMtx1(X2, size, 1); next
        cout << "A*A^(-1)" << endl;
    double** Z = new double* [size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Z[i] = new double[size];
    }
    double** Z1 = new double* [size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Z1[i] = new double[size];
    }
    int size2 = 1;
    ShowMtx1(F, size, size);
    ShowMtx1(T, size, size);
    MultiMass(F, T, Z, size, size);
    ShowMtx1(Z, size, size); next
        cout << "A^(-1)*A" << endl;
    MultiMass(T, F, Z1, size, size);
    ShowMtx1(T, size, size); next
        ShowMtx1(F, size, size); next
        ShowMtx1(Z, size, size); next



        return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int size, choice;
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tInput matrix A" << endl;//ввод матрицы A
    cout << "Enter the size of matrix A (>0,<=15)" << endl;
    cin >> size;
    while ((size < 0) || (size > 15)) { cout << "Enter the size of matrix A again" << endl; cin >> size; }
    //выход за пределы диапазона//
    double** A = new double* [size];//матрица A
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        A[i] = new double[size];
    }
label:
    cout << "1-Randomly(matrix A)\n2-Manually(matrix A) " << endl;//автоматически или вручную//
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        srand(time(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                A[i][j] = rand() % 20;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                cout << "A[" << i << "," << j << "]= ";
                cin >> A[i][j];
            }
            next
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        goto label;
    }
    }
    //clean

    double** C = new double* [size];// C - копия матрицы А
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        C[i] = new double[size]; C[i] = A[i];
    }
    double** T = new double* [size];// T-для обратной матрицы
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        T[i] = new double[size];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)//заполнение смежной матрицы T
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (i == j) { T[i][j] = 1.0; }
            else { T[i][j] = 0.0; }
        }
    }

    Gaussdet(A, T, C, size);
    //return 0;
}
```

Comment: На какой строчке, в какой функции конкретно появляется ошибка. Выложите только тот код, который может помочь решить проблему. Например у вас в какой-то функции ошибка, так выложите тот код, который как то связан с этой функцией. А не весь нагроможденный код с минимальным количеством комментариев. Я бы с радостью помог, но так лень весь код смотреть и разбираеться)

Comment: добавил конкретики)

Comment: выясните при каких входных значениях возникает ошибка и пошагово продебажте

Comment: Ваша функция "суммирования" `Summmtx` делает вычитание. Из матриц `B - B ` делает нулевую `X2 == 0` .

Comment: Создал [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1220335/267338) в котором программа уже не умирает и исполняется до конца и выводит все матрицы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина крэша программы в следующем, в функции `Summtx(...)` у вас есть цикл `for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)` по столбцам, он идёт до `size`. Но вы подаёте в вызове функции `Summmtx(B, B, X2, size);` матрицы у которых `size` строк но `1` столбец. В итоге цикл по `j` выходит за рамки матрицы и портит память, от этого программа умирает.

Один из вариантов исправления кода это сделать цикл `j` до `1`. Либо подавать нужно квадратную матрицу в функцию.

[Здесь полный исправленный код онлайн](https://tio.run/##3RntTttW9H@e4i5VJRuSJo5WaarjSA4a034wTVt@RNBMMsmFmDh2FDuFrkWirbpu6tbtUSgrhQKFV7CfiJ1z7di@jm0CtNq08JHr@3HOuef7HHdHo3LX0MzNy8s7utk1Jj1K6rplO2OqDRuFaG6oOf17/fhM19GHND6hW0PN1EeNwsTWzU1iakNqj7QuJbbTkwt3enRDNynpGlQzif3YduhQKHYNuyhGiybdcUjXmjj1OjV7hlx4ZOk98mPf2l5xdiShZ03WDbqwQNQS0U2H2PrPNBpJYqXiHniv3QP33H1HvGcEn7w9dx9mPrrH8H@ffR@6Z4UnBQIffYMI7Cj5QmEwRDbtL@JnwxoTARHoRCFVGb7qbB@MFhfFcFt0gDu05R/aCg5JMIyfmj2JH7w@qdfJhr5DeziwqTMa065u65YpfCkGU9vCV2yorumdta0ODoukKHPgdrknZG5hdimc9qeoYdPPyYT/Lg8CJhTgl6ndysRw9BXNtiO9a5VIOG7Gxu00fayBPnov3DPQuXP3PWgd071A8/J5msb8BB9rCUbyTGwHHMEj6WIZ@OAGId7B1WKZQl1USAuHgw4BPsAXTGZxfTdg625gy5PhcOjscKacytKliJGBXXuv3GPvmXs65SRYOGPvmfeawNe@9xxs/dj7BThciCtRsakUZd@1hJ4EMPnCkkSZVwr@VOqBuQRYqRAg59A9AhpPvd@950hgSDLQuQdaEXgk70/uAuC3CFOaA@@F94Zb8l7kKoaUqxRLoVJMDaYM0tN56WU6hpAx7ZpSxIHvoaeC7VGDOnQlIdpQhFeoPVlE2kN3EtHtg13rMJLlGDnRgjxDQixSNOenIR9/Mwt/E/EjuG@0iW33qJOu260M3Q6ICteWgSiTbk8nyBru6syjc2AlJ6A0FzP6BPahJq61DLfhEMXR7H4aD5Wri8tJXZRnPAandGpc53AltMzlqWUydspcDpDKhUg3bsxq8oTpA89BqSMnqW7GqM4jrFm4mpEM51ZnrYpox5rZE8S7Ndg1RTZdRLwPzeIMLa05aWnx7G3x7I2FyoiXhI5smcf2tenQMXH6bE03LDMhvq5ukkaDHQRPiQ6ROXUgBb2l@xGo@4DTQKDvQIn3B3P9Z@j@0Zsm6a5UGODtvg4ECQJAJg0F3DV5@pSwpzowVUQ2RkSOx8DyEpCVIFaoS6VGVYxojtMbMLZSYaksG69blkF0@7uJYYBwNjTIofLVCDxvur/DjJRZBGoXEpxhPyEyZzyhfOxdh9x9kG5OCN0/mcQb8uT7sQUSHRLLJD1d27RMzeD05pCF4GMMUPveS5QPig0eAzHhPHH/hj1@2n2OcsQ9@zB5jqt4vERAhOck0kIGBECfw89b77cwxhN8hn/er/D4FhzcYUjymDqTsTlNcKZCcS@CyHoI3ydICyOIkQdQ/ZAKYfg523YSBNRrxYQbOTzm8Lt96uCZkj@UZvOzUP6YzqK6icEpyLkkuTCzVwhgKqFa@Qo/hR@bnzfpLoJ@0EfaYw0Kt7E10EoQ05Rqwn6zE72YW4ASbyTHJ3rs@lLCNrJT0YhIBMWCxQDTTjkWnx2yoMQw3VhAqp/HkkoSGn5aWYu7hfQyaRBkNPOUSuHddP9un66OCvM8JbzeQsrt/BuGW1s5W2flPSvLyMENSINJtlzOLawHgTtEh43GN93@f2MVF1jVlMCaGXb54IpJpioqhNkkPGSVMGpprG/2HQLJAnjLR3RsU1js0Vhcy0qjeIjzkdXKQCe3FPUnoSyJaXjTIHK4oyI7PV2D9KFdjucC4O6x8oKI4QeRD4VrNDHaaWkdnza2a9mE1MqxHLw5XybZruWkkrcOTPklIcPt5@HNvDy8UslSlERtGEh6oZnM90KdZOvKvKqQmkrPU8dH3RsAC9vaV1f87VQUcxxUF9qZ11WubWy3pyedV@1a8mSQMs@wq804xvc74pctx6Xre7WgrdP0eV0Lb5aDPY2PST/BW97qjQu2hKGsXl3@RkilT4ZVuhpt2DyM8qRcy8s1nkiocBQ2rOYBWJ1LJwPzVhMi4tQHkK1K16A1I9bMF5FSyS4UUqoEv0sz1HRTmHZdoqZtt2/pXZpQ9YdO9POtOZrgaWes7xCVL6Xzug0pFTHLj6yNEBgRGtVSXZHui@lFMlMorrhlEOpQHfq5Pj41CJznq9tshNomcGG2uvU1N6yksOf60r/ZEdZQF6yh@Q7@TrHl6hd1F/B35Bd2gTuJ2l9ZcTIRrdXrm5Kab0mGtk6NBzz/pfIPkJhYQ@OxMOWD@NCslVc0c6IZ8VnCSRfKWKxVfZqB4lesBD7BEvjYr4QPvD2oKl9hjem9CZgQcDSuVva27nT7RPDn4jfqapApSQ8Sd7RZkwffsglVUZT/xdcxapgk@H0ncpfUqvnJbqIRsRvds/bgWq@XPsdrpaK6xkSss4cSG2@xcUdJvj@KCXOmUzn3@6UZTvTohgYuM8mKTcuxCFPe@Ga@38Tb2FJmLroERVV2Q9j96/pGt5RhdNOFmRZ92PvOJLJVBjdyiuRh22ePmVjQM@LovT6xrdt2uMH0j5h/Owcr/xh76cRakO9TyQyap7dtFWGXDls3W@jPW6HxSfeqckLf8G0tt6fK7@GK9PAFhcqygSUuOFcqsUh5eXm/IP0D)

Comment: Спасибо большое))) , такую мелочь не заметил